# Adding rows per group using Moving Average in Python

Tags: python, date, pandas-groupby, rows, moving-average

I have the following problem:
I have a table in which the customer number, the date and the sales are stored. The customer transactions are available on the first of each month. It may happen that a customer has not placed an order every month. The table looks like this:

| ID | Date | Revenues |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-05-01 | 100 |
| 1 | 2021-07-01 | 200 |
| 1 | 2021-08-01 | 100 |
| 1 | 2021-10-01 | 200 |
| 2 | 2021-12-01 | 300 |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 | 400 |

Now I want to add a certain number of rows to each group whose date is from today for a certain number of months in the future. The ID should remain the same, the date should be increased by one month and the turnover column should be filled with the moving average method.
The table should look like this:

| ID | Date | Revenues |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-05-01 | 100 |
| 1 | 2021-07-01 | 200 |
| 1 | 2021-08-01 | 100 |
| 1 | 2021-10-01 | 200 |
| 1 | 2022-04-01 | 150 |
| 1 | 2022-05-01 | 150 |
| 2 | 2021-12-01 | 300 |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 | 400 |
| 2 | 2022-04-01 | 350 |
| 2 | 2022-05-01 | 350 |

How can I solve this problem?
Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly:

```py
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])


def reindex(x):
    min_date = x["Date"].min()
    r = pd.date_range(min_date, min_date + pd.DateOffset(months=3), freq="MS")
    x = x.set_index("Date").reindex(r)
    x["ID"] = x["ID"].ffill().bfill()
    x["Revenues"] = x["Revenues"].fillna(x["Revenues"].mean())
    return x


x = df.groupby("ID", as_index=False).apply(reindex).droplevel(0).reset_index()
x = x.rename(columns={"index": "Date"})
print(x.to_markdown())
```

Prints:

|  | Date | ID | Revenues |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-12-01 00:00:00 | 1 | 100 |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 1 | 200 |
| 2 | 2022-02-01 00:00:00 | 1 | 150 |
| 3 | 2022-03-01 00:00:00 | 1 | 150 |
| 4 | 2021-12-01 00:00:00 | 2 | 300 |
| 5 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 2 | 400 |
| 6 | 2022-02-01 00:00:00 | 2 | 350 |
| 7 | 2022-03-01 00:00:00 | 2 | 350 |

Comment: Hello, 
Thank you very much for your answer. Your code works almost as I would like it to. I guess I didn't make myself quite clear, sorry. 
Two points: I changed the min_date to max so I have a future view. However, only the added rows are stored in x, but I would also need the old rows in my dataframe, then the moving average calculation would also fit. 
Is it possible to always add 3 more months starting from today's date?